# DOM window wont work

Tags: javascript, dom, alert

Im using DOM window ( http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html ) to create alerts.  However the content that goes in the windows is under the `id inline content`.

However the js file doesnt do anything with this `id` and the content inside isn't showing up.

Is there a css file im missing because the window appears but with nothing in it?

p.s. I'm using example one

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely need to use this DOM Window plugin, I'd recommend just using simple javascript or jquery commands to achieve this rather simple task.

But anyways, since you're using example one, you need to make sure that the `href` on the `a` tag that you use for your Open DOMWindow function is pointing to the div that houses the content.